# JQuery Change not triggering at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple drop down as follows

```
 <select id="drg-select" name="drg-select">
<option>Select DRG</option>
<option value="1"> PSYCHOSES</option>
<option value="2"> HEART FAILURE & SHOCK W CC</option>
<option value="3"> MAJOR JOINT REPLACEMENT OR REATTACHMENT OF LOWER EXTREMITY W/O MCC</option>
<option value="4"> SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV 96+ HOURS W MCC</option>
<option value="5"> INTRACRANIAL HEMORRHAGE OR CEREBRAL INFARCTION W CC</option>
<option value="6"> CHRONIC OBSTRUCTIVE PULMONARY DISEASE W CC</option>........
</select>
```

and this is how i am handling the Change event

```
       jQuery('select[name="drg-select"]').change(function() {
                alert('i am here');
            });
```

its pretty simple but it is not triggered at all please tell me , what i am missing. Also i have tested other events like ready etc and my JS/Jquery is already linked.

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle for it please? :)

Comment: Works for me here, http://jsfiddle.net/ZXHkR/

Comment: When are you attaching this event? Is this wrapped in a document.ready of some kind?

Comment: I think you missed to include jquery core library

Comment: Have you included jquery core library?

Comment: You may want to change your element to just $('#drg-select'). It's an ID, you might aswell make life easier for yourself :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes your suggestion I have already implemented in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is working correctly. May be you have not binded the event on correct time. Try binding the event on document ready.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SWNE5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('select[name="drg-select"]').change(function() {
            alert('i am here');
        });
});
```

Comment: Why in your demo alert is not fired?

Comment: It is firing. check the fiddle.

Comment: I am checking this in IE10 browser, the browser might be issue.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: My code is already working but why to bind it with ready event? from working i mean i used same code in some previous project.

Comment: Strange thing that its working with ready but it should be triggered independently

Comment: It is because dom is not loaded  at the moment you are trying to bind it. writing the event in ready ensures that dom is loaded completely.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the JQuery core file and under that you need to write the your script:

Code for including JS and Jquery code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#drg-select").change(function() {
       alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
});
```

See working demo :
[**View Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fPV6F/17/)

Comment: Strange thing that its working with ready but it should be triggered independently.

Comment: @temp-learn you can call it independtly if you put this script at bottom of your page and the include JS file at starting or in `<head>` of your page.

Comment: @temp-learn also you need to put your `<select>` tag before your script.